# EXTJS 3.X - Prevent TreePanel from auto-loading

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to prevent autoloading of the Treeloader in extjs 3.x?

Is their a workaround to achieve something similar to autoload:false?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer helpful on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?108692-CLOSED-ExtJS-TreePanel-deferred-load-rootVisible-false) - configure "directFn" on the TreeLoader, and then set it to null when you actually want to load the store.